# Citing acronyms with acro package

Tags: citing, acronyms, acro

using the `cite` and `cite-cmd` features of the `acro` package seems to have at least two problems for me.

1. When an acronym occurs only once, it is spelled out without the abbreviation, which is fine.  However, I would like the citation to still be printed (the first time at least)!
2. When using the author-year citation style, two consecutive parenthesis aren't particularly pleasing. I'd like to have something like (AIS, Neal 2009) instead of (AIS) (Neal 2009). Is this possible?

The points are illustrated by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@article{neal2001annealed,
    title = {{Annealed importance sampling}},
    author = {Neal, R},
    journal = {Statistics and Computing},
    year = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[natbib,citestyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{single,sort,cite-cmd=\citep}
\DeclareAcronym{AIS}{
  short=AIS,long=Annealed Importance Sampling,cite={neal2001annealed}
}
\DeclareAcronym{AIS2}{
  short=AIS,long=Annealed Importance Sampling,cite={neal2001annealed}
}
\begin{document}
   This \ac{AIS} lacks the citation, because it only occurs once!

   This \ac{AIS2} occurs twice (\ac{AIS2}), but has double parenthesis, I'd prefer (AIS, \textbackslash \texttt{citealp\{key\}})

   \printacronyms
\end{document}
```

[image: result of mwe]

Comment: Both is not possible with `acro` with the current version – at least not without redefining internal macros. But I'll gladly try to add support (and will post an answer here once I've done so). You can follow the progress here https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issue/39 and here https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issue/40

Comment: This will be possible in v2.0. I'll add an answer once it's published

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v2.0 (2015/08/17) there are the options `group-citation` and `group-cite-cmd`:

```
\acsetup{
  group-citation = true ,
  group-cite-cmd = \citealp
}
```

`acro` now (since v2.0) also adds the citation to a single use (IMHO this makes a lot more sense than omitting it).

A full example:

[image]

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246008/
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{neal2001annealed,
  title   = {Annealed importance sampling} ,
  author  = {Neal, R} ,
  journal = {Statistics and Computing} ,
  year    = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[natbib,citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{acro}[2015/08/16]
\acsetup{
  single         = true ,
  sort           = true ,
  cite-cmd       = \citep ,
  group-citation = true ,
  group-cite-cmd = \citealp
}

\DeclareAcronym{AIS}{
  short = AIS,
  long = Annealed Importance Sampling,
  cite = {neal2001annealed}
}
\DeclareAcronym{AIS2}{
  short = AIS,
  long = Annealed Importance Sampling,
  cite = {neal2001annealed}
}

\begin{document}

\ac{AIS} -- only used once

\ac{AIS2} and \ac{AIS2} -- used twice

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```