# acronym package and apacite - citation: Brackets arround (acronym; Autor, Year)

Tags: citing, acronyms, brackets, apacite

I am using the `acronym` package and have a problem with formating:

```
\usepackage[acronym]
\newacro{FWA}{Full Written Acronym}

with \ac{FWA} \cite{FWA_paper} it looks like this:
```

`(FWA) (J. Doe, 2016)`

however i need it to look like this (this is what APA standard is)

`Full Written Acronym (FWA; J. Doe, 2016)`

one workaround I found is to write it like this:

```
\acl{FWA} ( \acf{FWA}; \citeNP{FWA_paper})
```

However then the next time I use `\ac{FWA}` it again writes the full version, since it is the first time it occurs in the text.

Any solutions?

EDIT:

I found a solution using python ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput
fileToSearch = 'myDocument.tex'
acroList = ["FOO","BAR","ACRO3"]

# replace all \ac with \acs
for acro in acroList:
    textToSearch = "\\ac{" + acro + "}"
    textToReplace = "\\acs{" + acro + "}"
    with fileinput.FileInput(fileToSearch, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')

# replace the first occurence in the file with the long + short + cite version
for acro in acroList:
    first = 1
    textToSearch = "\\acs{" + acro + "}"
    textToReplace = "\\acl{" + acro + "}(" "\\acs{" + acro + "};\\citeNP{XXXXXXXX" + acro + "})"
    with fileinput.FileInput(fileToSearch, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            newLine = line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace,1)
            if newLine.find("XXXXXXXX" + acro) > -1 & first == 1:
                first = 0
                print(newLine, end='')
            else:
                print(line, end='')
```

after running the script you have to copy your citations to the XXXXXXACRO space holders.
Not the perfect solution, but it works for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Should the short version of the acronym always be `(FWA; J. Doe, 2016)` or only when the acronym is first defined and `FWA` for all subsequent appearances.

Comment: Only the first time it appears it should be
Full Written Acronym (FWA; J. Doe, 2016)
the subsequent apperance should be just FWA

Comment: Are you open to answers using the `acro` package?

Comment: Yes, using the acro package would also be an option.

Comment: So revisiting this it turns out this can be done with [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package as described in [Citing acronyms with acro package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246008/106162) which covers at least a similar output.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a similar workaround, adding the  `\glsunset` command, which solves the issue with the repeated full acronym version, like this:

```latex
\Acl{bpe} \glsunset{bpe} (\acs{bpe}; \citealp{sennrich-etal-2016-neural})
```

which gets rendered as:

> Byte-pair encoding (BPE; Sennrich et al., 2016)

All subsequent usages of `\ac{bpe}` will be rendered as "BPE".